# ErrorException Undefined variable: users (View: resources\views\admin\dashboard.blade.php)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

hi I wants to show users list into my dashboard pannel but it shows me this problem :

**ErrorException
Undefined variable: users (View: resources\views\admin\dashboard.blade.php)**

Controller File :

```
 public function index()
{
    $listuser = User::all();
    return view('admin.dashboard',['users' => $listuser]);
    //return view('admin.dashboard')->with('users', $listuser);
}
```

blade file :

```html
 <div id="utilisateurs">
                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Id</th>
                                            <th>Nom et Prenom</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>tele</th>
                                            <th>adresse</th>
                                            <th>date de creation</th>
                                            <th>Statut de compte</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead><br>
                                    <tbody>
                                        
                                        @foreach($users as $user)
                                            @if($user->role_as=='0')
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->tele }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->adresse }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->created_at}}</td>
                                            <td>Null</td>
                                        </tr>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Routes :

```
  Route::middleware(['auth','isAdmin'])->group(function() {
Route::get('/dashboard','Admin\FrontendController@index');


/*users routes*/
Route::get('/dashboard', 'UserController@index');
```

Comment: You seem to have two routes using different controllers for the same URL? Which is used? Which did you post? Are you sure that's the controller used? Too many unknowns here

Comment: yes the 1st route shows the admin panel , and the 2nd route get the users list from the controller , here's the 1st index function , FrontendController@index : public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.